# Given two ordered lists, iterate through pairs in order of sum

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, queue, stack

I am given two ordered lists list1 and list2. I want to iterate through pairs (x, y) where x is in list1 and y is in list2, in order of the sum of the pairs. I do not care in which order I output pairs with the same sum.

E.g. given [1, 2, 3], [2, 4, 6], I should output:

(1, 2), (2, 2), (1, 4), (3, 2), (2, 4), (1, 6), (3, 4), (2, 6), (3, 6)

with the sums being: 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 9

I am not interested in approaches which merge the lists somehow, then sort it. For example, in general, I do not want to have to do some amount of work which depends on the sizes of the lists, before I have output the pair with the 20th smallest sum.

What is one algorithm that meets these requirements?

Comment: What is holding you back? There is no question here. Why have you tagged with `queue` and `stack`? Do you have an attempt that uses these data structures?

Comment: I have not thought much about it, but I strongly suspect the correct solution involves these data structures. Apologies, I have added a concrete question.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a minheap data structure.

An entry in the heap would be a tuple with a sum, and the two indices that contribute to this sum.

A helper data structure must ensure that the heap does not have duplicate entries, i.e. two entries that have the same index pair. A simple hashset can serve for that.

Start with just one entry on the heap based on the indices (0, 0).

Then loop while there are entries in the heap and each time pull the minimal element from the heap (with minimum sum), output it, and then add two entries to the heap which each have incremented one of the two indices. If such entry is already in the heap, ignore it, or if the next index is out of range, ignore it.

Here is an implementation in Python (which has native heap support):

```py
from heapq import heappush, heappop

def mergebysum(a, b):
    heap = [(a[0] + b[0], 0, 0)]
    inheap = set([(0, 0)])
    while heap:
        _, i, j = heappop(heap)
        inheap.remove((i, j))
        yield a[i], b[j]
        if i + 1 < len(a) and (i + 1, j) not in inheap:
            heappush(heap, (a[i+1]+b[j], i+1, j))
            inheap.add((i+1, j))
        if j + 1 < len(b) and (i, j + 1) not in inheap:
            heappush(heap, (a[i]+b[j+1], i, j+1))
            inheap.add((i, j+1))
```

Here is an example run:

```py
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [2, 4, 6]
for x, y in mergebysum(a, b):
    print((x, y))
```

The output is as you have listed in your question.

This solution has a space complexity of O(+), where  and  are the sizes of the two input lists. The time complexity is determined by the output size and the heap overhead, i.e. O(log(+)).